# How to create a blog background with white content

Tags: html, css, blogger

I've been searching how to do this for the whole week, with no avail
I'd like to create a blog design like this: http://www.bedinthekitchen.co.uk
where the background is like a frame and the content is white..
when i add a background it tiles the whole page and the content is transparent.

Comment: give a background:white ; to content; to hide page background

Comment: Like this? http://jsfiddle.net/borglinm/6n5EJ/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To prevent your background from tiling do the following:

```
html{
    background: #fff ("../image/mybackgroundimg.jpg") 0 0 no-repeat fixed;
    background-size:cover;
}
```

[***DEMO***](http://jsfiddle.net/lotusms/8qYh8/3/)

Comment: how do i stop there being too much background at the top?

Comment: If you look at  margin: 20px auto; in the container, that 20px means the white container will be 20px down from the top and push everything under it 20 px as well. You can increase and decrease this number. If you mean you want less white showing in the container then it's the padding you need to adjust.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a really quick recreation of the layout for the website you posted a link to.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <head>
          <title>Blog</title>
          <style>
               body {background-color:#F7D4B0;}
               #content {background: white; width:1100px; height:500px; margin:100px auto;}
          </style>
    </head>

    <body>
         <div id="content">
            <h1 style="text-align:center;">Blog</h1>
            <p style="text-align:center;">Content</p>
         </div>
    </body>

</html>
```

You can change the background of the body to whatever you want. As long as you keep all of your content within the "content" div, which has a background set to white, you should be set.